# Find the biggest element in a three-dimensional array in C

Tags: arrays, c

My task is to output the highest temperature value from a three-dimensional array. Unfortunately, the program always outputs 9.6, which corresponds to the index 0 0 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
double max_temperature_week(double temperature[52][7][24]){
    int i,j,k;
    double max = temperature[0][0][0];
  
    for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 24; k++){
                if(temperature[i][j][k] > max){
                    temperature[i][j][k] = max;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
  
    return max;
}
  
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    double temperature[52][7][24] = {{

            {9.6, 9.4, 9.3, 9.1, 7.9, 7.7, 7.3, 7.2, 8.8, 9.3, 9.7, 9.4, 10.2, 9.7, 9.9, 9.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.2, 7.1, 6.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.2},
            {4.9, 4.6, 4.6, 4.1, 3.5, 3.1, 2.6, 2.6, 3.5, 5.1, 6.2, 8.3, 9.0, 9.3, 9.1, 8.0, 6.8, 6.4, 5.4, 5.2, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5},
            {6.3, 6.8, 7.0, 7.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.1, 7.4, 7.7, 8.2, 8.7, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.6, 8.4, 8.0, 7.9, 7.7, 7.6, 7.5, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2},
            {7.1, 7.0, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.2, 7.5, 7.7, 8.1, 8.3, 8.0, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 7.7, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9},
            {8.1, 8.0, 7.9, 7.8, 7.5, 7.2, 6.9, 7.2, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 8.7, 8.9, 9.0, 7.8, 8.5, 8.1, 7.7, 7.7, 6.7, 7.0, 6.5, 7.1},
            {6.4, 6.6, 6.3, 5.8, 5.0, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9, 5.3, 6.1, 5.5, 5.3, 5.7, 5.8, 6.5, 6.6, 5.8, 5.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.3, 5.8},
            {4.4, 4.0, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3.8, 4.4, 5.2, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1, 6.7, 6.3, 5.9, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.7, 7.2, 7.7}

                               }}; 
    printf("Largest in given array is %lf", max_temperature_week(temperature));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign the first value to all elements of the array having value larger than max.

It has to be:

```
max = temperature[i][j][k];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I replace your code with mine, there is still the same output 9.6

Comment: @check1_07: Re “When I replace your code with mine, there is still the same output 9.6”: Try replacing your code with theirs, not theirs with yours. I did, and the output is “10.200000”. Save the source file and recompile.

Comment: Definitely, it works https://godbolt.org/z/jPazEo841